# Wifi Problem: Connection failed (Activation of network connection failed)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager, tp-link

I am using TP-link TL823N V2 wiresless adapter. Everytime I start the computer, the wifi is stopped from connecting with the message Connection Failed (Activation of network connection failed), even though it shows available networks. It connects after I unplug and replug the wifi adapter. The only problem I have that each time I start the pc, I have to unplug and replug my adapter from the back of the CPU Cabinet.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Use below command and it will work. I had similar issue. Thank me later.

```
echo "options 8192eu rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/8192eu.conf
echo "blacklist rtl8xxxu" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8xxxu.conf
```

Comment: @saying things like "It will work" and "Thank me later" are unhelpful. People will normally thank you if something helps them asking for it really doesn't help. What would be helpful is expanding on your answer explaining what the proposed commands do and why that solves the problem.